# What Regex would I use to match file names with the format 'number-text-text'?

Tags: c#, sql, regex

I have code that searches a folder that contains SQL patch files. I want to add file names to an array if they match the following name format:

`number-text-text.sql`

What Regex would I use to match `number-text-text.sql`?

Would it be possible to make the Regex match file names where the `number` part of the file name is between two numbers? If so what would be the Regex syntax for this?

Comment: Define `text`. Letters, spaces, punctuation, numbers?

Comment: Also define `number` and `between two numbers`. A couple of example would help to prevent misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex make it halfway there:

```
\d+-[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+\.sql
```

Regarding to match in a specific range it gets trickier as regex doesn't have a simple way to handle ranges. To limit the match to a filename with a number between 2 and 13 this is the regex:

```
([2-9]|1[0-3])-[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+\.sql
```

Comment: `\w` matches both letters, underscores and digits.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select '4-dfsg-asdfg.sql' ~ E'^[0-9]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+\\.sql$'
```

This restricts the TEXT to simple ASCII characters. May or may not be what you want.
This is tested in PostgreSQL. Regular expression flavors differ a lot between implementations. You probably know that?

Anchors at begin `^` and end `$` are optional, depending how you are going to do it.

Comment: Probably just a typo but your second `a` in the characters classes should be uppercases.

Comment: [0-9] is the same as \d, not sure why you have escaped backslashes everywhere, but you don't need to backslash dashes. also, why not use [a-z] with an i flag instead of [a-zA-Z]?

Comment: @Jesse: Regular expressions differ between implementations. OP did not disclose in what context the regexp is needed. I tried to formulate as generic as possible. `[0-9]` or `\d`, both are simple enough for the number character class.

Comment: Hmm, OP tagged the question with C#, so I assumed they were cool with PCRE. that aside, unless the OP plans on doing postgres specific regexes, the double backslashes are unnecessary, as are all the a-zA-Z, as opposed to just making it case insensitive.

Comment: @Jesse: It is also tagged [sql], but I'll remove the backslashes. Making it case insensitive is usually slower than using an occasional `a-zA-Z` instead of `a-z`. It also introduces a subtle error: `sql` is defined lower case in the question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - good call, usually file extensions are insensitive, but I agree. Totally missed the sql tag, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

`\d+-[^-]+-[^-]+\.sql`

Edit: You want just letters, so here it is without specific ranges.

`\d+-[a-z]+-[a-z]+\.sql` - You'll also want to use the `i` flag, not sure how that's done in c#, but here it is in js/perl:

`/\d+-[a-z]+-[a-z]+\.sql/i`

Ranges are more difficult. Here's an example of how to match 0-255:

`([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])`

So to match (0-255)-text-text.sql, you'd have this:

`/^(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])-[a-z]+-[a-z]+\.sql/i`

(I put the digits in a non-capturing group and matched from the beginning of the string to prevent partial matches on the number and in case you're expecting numbered groups or something).

Basically every time you need another digit of possibility, you'll need to add a new condition inside this case. The smaller the digit you'd like to match, the more cases you'll need as well. What is your desired min/max? AFAIK there's not a simple way to do this dynamically (although I'd love for someone to show me I'm wrong about that).

The simplest way to get around this would be to simply capture the digits, and use native syntax to see if it's in your range. Example in js:

```
var match = filename.match(/(\d+)-[a-z]+-[a-z]+\.sql/i);
if(match && match[1] < maximumNumber && match[1] > minimumNumber){
    doStuff();
}
```

Comment: `[^-]` allows much more than just letters.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression should be:

```
(\d+)-[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+\.sql
```

You would then use the first captured group to check if your number is between the two numbers you desire. Don't try to check if a number is within a range with a regular expression; do it in two steps. Your code will be much clearer for it.